# setImageResource from Filepath (Gallery?) com.edmodo.cropper

Tags: java, android, crop

Im using the Cropper (com.edmodo.cropper) to crop images.
Can i crop an image from the gallery?
How can i put the image from path to the CropImageView?

its not working, can someone tell me another crop pack to crop images from path with the same features?

Comment: Do you have the Uri of the gallery photo already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the bitmap from the URI and then display it inside the CropperImageView.

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
cropper.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

You  would probably need to keep the process of retrieving Bitmap off the UI thread. You can, for example, wrap the first line in AsyncTask. I prefer using libraries such as Picasso or UniversalImageLoader for this purpose.

Comment: i get following error Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type 
  CropImageView
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type 
  CropImageView

Comment: @CoXxIndustries You need an instance of CropImageView.
You can treat CropImageView just like normal ImageView: you need to put it in your layout file, then find it using findViewById(R.id.id_of_imageview) and after that you can call `cropper.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but what do u mean... ?

Comment: oh i have this -> CropImageView cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView); and the code from u are under this...

Comment: You are probably getting this warning because you are trying to call `CropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`. Am I right?

Comment: @CoXxIndustries make sure you have `cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` and not `CropImageView.setImageBimap(bitmap)`